# Post a input 'file' using jQuery

Tags: jquery, file, post

Is it possible to post a `<input type=“file” id="file" />` using this:

```
$.post("_sys/cmd.php", { file: $("#file").val() },
            function(data){
                if (data == "Success") {
                    $("#warn").html("<em>File Uploaded!</em>");
                }
});
```

Tried using `$("#file").val()` but no joy.
If it isn't possible, is there another way? Thanks. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery

Comment: Ah. So even if I didn't want to upload the file using jQuery, it's not possible without one of those plugins? I only want to pass the upload info to another PHP script using jQuery. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You just need the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). The code will be something like it:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#form_upload').ajaxForm(function() { 
            alert("Thank you for your upload!"); 
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```